# "clear" command error: terminals database is inaccessible (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: command-line, 18.04, bash, bashrc, reset

After updating an Ubuntu 18.04 system using `apt update` and `apt upgrade`, running the command `clear` after connecting to the system via SSH results in the error

> terminals database is inaccessible

How can we troubleshoot this to fix the problem?

---

```
$ clear
terminals database is inaccessible
```

```
$ $TERM
xterm-256color: command not found
```

```
$ reset
reset: can't initialize terminal type xterm-256color (error -1)
Terminal type?
```

```
$ sudo /lib/terminfo/x/xterm-256color
sudo: /lib/terminfo/x/xterm-256color: command not found
```

```
$ ls -l /lib/terminfo/x/xterm-256color 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3525 May 23  2018 /lib/terminfo/x/xterm-256color
```

```
$ strace -etrace=open clear
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

```
$ strace -etrace=access clear
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

```
$ conda
-bash: /home/bar/anaconda/bin/conda: /home/foo/anaconda/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

**~/.bashrc**

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
```

Comment: `strace -etrace=access clear` might be more diagnostic. Does `/lib/terminfo/x/xterm-256color` exist? is it readable?

Comment: @steeldriver Updated question with the output of running `strace -etrace=access clear` and `sudo /lib/terminfo/x/xterm-256color`. Seems like `xterm-256color` does not exist, but in another identical Ubuntu 18.04 system (without Anaconda installed), `xterm-256color` also does not exist but `clear` works fine for it.

Comment: My intention was for you to run something like `ls -l /lib/terminfo/x/xterm-256color`

Comment: @steeldriver Gotcha, the output is `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3525 May 23  2018 /lib/terminfo/x/xterm-256color`

Comment: OK thanks - in that case I'm stumped, sorry (I was expecting it to be missing or unreadable)

Comment: @steeldriver No problem, thanks for helping!

Comment: I guess it might be worth trying `sudo apt install --reinstall ncurses-base` as a hail-mary

Comment: @steeldriver Reinstalled (ncurses-base 6.1-1ubuntu1.18.04) as suggested and re-logged in to the server via SSH. Problem persists... worth a try :)